# How can I convert a Unicode codepoint (\uXXXX) into a character in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, codepoint

I have some unicode codepoints (\u5315\u4e03\u58ec\u4e8c\u4e0a\u53b6\u4e4b), which I have to convert into actual characters they represent.

What's the simplest way to do so?

Comment: No, I'm looking for code to convert them.

Comment: Convert them where? As far it really sounds like as if you want to load some file, parse those codepoints, replace with actual glyphs/characters and then save the file.

Comment: Sorry, but you make things complicated :) I don't need to load any files and save them, but I do need to convert unicode codepoint into the actual character, which I mentioned in my question. "Convert them where?" - obviously in the Perl script (convert a string with codepoints to the string with characters - easy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could [Unicode::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Unicode-Escape) be what you need?

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes I'd just use [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $string = '\\u5315\\u4e03\\u58ec\\u4e8c\\u4e0a\\u53b6\\u4e4b';

$string =~ s/\\u(....)/ pack 'U*', hex($1) /eg;

print $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -C -E'say"\x{5315}\x{4e03}\x{58ec}\x{4e8c}\x{4e0a}\x{53b6}\x{4e4b}"'
```

or funny way

```
perl -C -E'say map chr hex, qw(5315 4e03 58ec 4e8c 4e0a 53b6 4e4b)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use JSON::XS
print JSON::XS->new->decode('{"a":"\u5315\u4e03\u58ec\u4e8c\u4e0a\u53b6\u4e4b"}')->{a}
```

Comment: Tried exactly what you suggested, but unfortunately it didn't give me any output...