# How to handle unicode in \uXXXX format?

Tags: json, perl, unicode

If have the text:

> "Conseil de discipline de l\u0027Ordre des comptables professionnels
>   agréés du Québec"

How do I deal with the `\u0027`, which is obviously an apostrophe of some sort.  How can I convert this to a readable character?

The data comes from `JSON`.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~you/Encode-Escape-0.14/lib/Encode/Escape/Unicode.pm

Comment: @ysth Didn't work. I decoded the full JSON string using `decode_json` and it still printed out the literal "\u0027" when I dumped the object.

Comment: @CJ7 show your original json?  it sounds like it may be doubly encoded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Unicode codepoint (\uXXXX) into a character in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667599/how-can-i-convert-a-unicode-codepoint-uxxxx-into-a-character-in-perl)

Comment: How could this question possibly be 'too broad' ?

Answer (score 1):

```
use utf8;
use JSON::XS;
use open OUT => ':utf8';
my $decoder = JSON::XS->new->allow_nonref(1);
my $json_string = '"Conseil de discipline de l\\u0027Ordre des comptables professionnels agréés du Québec"';
printf "in: %s\nout: %s\n", $json_string, $decoder->decode($json_string);
```

works for me. (use utf8 needed for literal utf8 in the perl source, allow_nonref needed to decode a just a string, not an object or array)

If indeed you do have some doubly-encoded strings, you could do:

```
$string =~ s/\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4})/chr hex $1/g;
```

Comment: I am getting a `Wide character in subroutine entry` error on the `decode_json` line.

Comment: It seems like the `use open OUT => ':utf8';` is unnecessary.  Am I correct?